# What is the source for Diogenes' quote in Burton's The Anatomy of Melancholy?

Tags: philosophy

In **[The Anatomy of Melancholy](https://archive.org/details/McGillLibrary-RBSC_QUATRO-2497-17110/page/n687)**, Robert Burton states that

> *"When the son swore, Diogenes struck the father."*

Where did Burton get this from? I can find no earlier (i.e. Classical) reference to it, nor any suggestion that Diogenes in fact did it. I am wondering if Burton made it up and, as it were," hung" it on Diogenes.

---

**Edit**: The nearest I can find to Burton's claim is this (unreferenced)  quote:

*"Why not whip the teacher when the pupil misbehaves?"*

http://millionsofmouths.com/diogenes.html

Comment: What are you looking for evidence of, that the quote existed before Burton used it or that Diogenes actually struck a father when his son swore?

Comment: @SteveBird Either, really. Both Wikipedia and Encyclopaedia Britannica mention the other stories of Diogenes - looking for an honest man with a lantern, telling Alexander the Great not to block the sun - but the *earliest* reference I can find to this alleged quote is Burton, and I'm wondering where he got it from, or whether he just "hung" it on Diogenes?

Comment: Diogenes Laertius' entry on Diogenes of Sinope in "Lives and Opinions of Eminent Philosophers" (book 6) doesn't mention it.

Comment: This list of quotes by and about Diogenes does not include it:  https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Diogenes_of_Sinope

Comment: @LuísHenrique I know! :) Diogenes Laertius wrote about Diogenes of Sinope in his "Lives and Opinions of Eminent Philosophers". You can read it here: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0258%3Abook%3D6%3Achapter%3D2

Comment: It seems to me this is only a metaphor that would imply that when a child swore, he used Diogenes' speeches to strike at him, what people call "roasting". Diogenes stroke at many people by insulting them or by just promoting a "rebellious mindset", when you're a father you really wish your son isn't gonna do like Diogenes, E.G. urinating in public etc etc

Comment: Here's a quote from Diogenes Laertius, Lives of Eminent Philosophers, 6.2.62: Seeing the child of a courtesan throw stones at a crowd, he cried out, "Take care you don't hit your father." An alternative translation is found in the URL you provided as following: When Diogenes noticed a prostitute's son throwing rocks at crowd, Diogenes said to him "Careful, son. Don't hit your father." This seems to be the only quote that's somehow relevant.

Comment: @mooncatcher Thanks for that, it does appear that Burton "hung" the idea on Diogenes. The other point about the prostitute's son is the implication that he probably didn't know who his father was ;-) - which sounds like Diogenes!

Comment: I think you found the source, which was creatively rephrased. This site has the citation to Davenport's translation of Diogenes for the quote: https://www.azquotes.com/quote/659481

Comment: @AaronBrick Great find, thanks! If you'd like to make that an answer, I'd accept it! This has been bugging me for years! :-)

Comment: It's pretty insubstantial, but I'm happy to help, TheHonRose!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think *you* found the source, which was creatively rephrased. [A-Z Quotes](http://azquotes.com/quote/659481) has the citation to Davenport's translation of Diogenes for the quote:

> Herakleitos, Diogenes (2011). “Herakleitos and Diogenes: Translated from the Greek by Guy Davenport”, p.55, Wipf and Stock Publishers

Comment: I may have found the source, but couldn't find the *source* of the *source*! ;-)